# How to set the value of any property in an object using a variable?

Tags: php, properties, stdclass

I have an object with different levels of depth.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [color] => green 
        )
    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [optgroup] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [4] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [OPTION] => 
                        )
                    [5] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [OPTION] => stdClass Object
                                (                            
                                    [2] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [DataSubtext] => SUBTEXT of
                                        )
                                    [3] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [DataIcon] => glyphicon-heart
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I want to edit this object's data in a html page and need to access specific properties after they are clicked. But I don't know the depth in advance, i.e. 'color' is level 2 but 'THEOPT' is level 6.
When I create a string with the path (e.g. $string = ' {9} -> optgroup -> {2} -> OPTION -> {2} ->  THEOPT  ') and add it after

`$var = $myobject -> $string ;`

I would have to use eval to get and set the property but that should be avoided. 
I thought about case ... for each level, i.e.

```
switch ($depth) ...
case 1...
case 2...
```

So how can I address any property with a variable in the best possible way?
I came up with this solution. It is a recursive function that returns the three properties I need. The array is the properties as array, i.e. 9, optgroup,2, etc.

I wonder that php does not provide an easy interface to edit an object precisely.

```
    function getObjectValue ( $object, $array ){
  if ( $array[1] == ''  )  {
     $f = new stdClass;
     $f -> POS  =  $array[0];
     foreach( $object -> {$array[0]} as $key  => $value ) {
         $f -> name = $key;
         $f -> value = $value;
    }
  return $f ;}
 if (  is_object(  $object -> {$array[0]} )   ){
     $next = array_shift($array) ;
     $result = getObjectValue(  $object -> {$next} ,  $array );
     }
  return $result;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is can solve your problem, Anyway

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($your_std_class_object), true);
```

this will get your object in an array format, so by using the array you can simply iterate, and check whether this has some child and, find out the depth of the array,.

Comment: Well, converting to array and then using array_filter ... but I was looking for a rather easy way of addressing any property.